# Is the zero trust approach really so safe?

Tags: banks, trust, threat-modeling, zero-trust

Recently, I see so many emerging vendors that are advertising their use of zero-trust. What potential risks are we exposed to if we shift to zero-trust in our bank?

Comment: This question is very broad and is missing essential context. It is not even clear if you are talking about  online banking from the customer perspective or networks inside a bank. It is also not clear where exactly zero trust would be applied there.

Comment: I think I have a very good answer here but some reason you think its a bad question.

Comment: I tried to explain what is bad on the question in order to help you to improve it. Others seem to agree - even the one who added the answer. And just because somebody was able to figure out from a  question what you really wanted to know does not mean that the question is actually good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero trust tends to increase security. If done excessively, then security becomes excessive and that occurs at the expense of usability, as the two are often (though not always) inversely proportional to each other. Is it *safe* from a strict security standpoint? Absolutely, but it may not be what you want. If your goal is to avoid getting hacked (for example) and you succeed by having excessive security, it won't do you any good if it results in no one using your bank because it's so tedious to deal with.

Would, say, doing a strip search on customers entering bank premises increase security? Definitely! Will it result in you actually saving money because there are fewer incidents? No, because everyone will avoid your bank like the plague. You must find the proper balance between security and practicality. This is called [risk assessment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IT_risk_management#Risk_assessment) and must be done by any serious company that wants to succeed.

Honestly though? It seems like these vendors are just using the term as a meaningless buzzword.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like few guys decided it's bad question but the answer was exactly what I was looking for.